# Return Python numdifftools.Jacobian matrix

Tags: python, matrix, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to write Python code that will return a Jacobian matrix. After installing numdifftools and running the in-built function `numdifftools.Jacobian()` I get this:

```
numdifftools.core.Jacobian object at 0x1032fe2d0
```

All examples I find online return this result for me. Is there a command I'm missing or am I miss-interpreting how this function works??

```
# To approximate a solution for a series of 
# overdeterministic, non-linear equations.
# Find the point of intersection

import scipy
import numpy as np
import numdifftools as nd 

# The matrix A, equations stored in rows in the form:
# [x^2, y^2, x, y]
def MatrixA():
return np.matrix([  [1, 1, 0, 0],
                    [1, 1, 4, -2],
                    [0, 0, 4, -2],
                    [4, 0, 22, -9],
                    [5, 0, 0, 1]
                    ])

# The matrix B, the answers of the equations in Matrix A
def MatrixB():
    return np.matrix([  [16],
                        [6],
                        [-13],
                        [31.5204],
                        [1.288]
                        ])


#Using the Moore-Penrose method to solve 
#an overdetermined set of equations
def MoorePenrose(A):
    Ans = A.getT() * A
    Ans = Ans.getI()
    Ans = Ans * A.getT()
    return Ans

# Linearise the equations by using the Newton method
# This will generate the best possible linear version
# of the nonlinear system.
def Linearise(A):
    return nd.Jacobian(A)

#=============================================
# Program Main() {
#=============================================

#Read in A matrix of equations
A = MatrixA()

#Read in B matrix of solutions (RHS of A Matrices equations)
B = MatrixB()

#Solution => 
#Linearise Matrix A
A = Linearise(A)
print A

#A = Moorse Penrose psuedoinverse of A
A = MoorePenrose(A)

#Unknowns Matrix X = A * B
A = A * B

# Print out the unknowns Matrix.
print A

#=============================================
# } Main End;
#=============================================
```

Comment: I think Jacobian(A) returns a function you have to then use, but I know nothing about this libary ;) http://pydoc.net/Python/Numdifftools/0.7.7/numdifftools.core/

Comment: Like to make this more clear: I get this result: numdifftools.core.Jacobian object at 0x1032fe2d0, when I try and print the Matrix after using numdifftools.Jacobian().

Comment: To make it clear, I don't understand the math at all. But I see that you can't just print out the result of Jacobian(A), the result is an object you have to keep working with. I suggest you try it in ipython or some other REPL first.

Answer (score 1):

Investigating the same question for multiple output function of multiple variables, I made this simple example demonstrating the use of numdifftools [Jacobian](http://numdifftools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/generated/numdifftools.core.Jacobian.html?highlight=Jacobian) function.

**Please note the use of numpy array to define function multiple outputs and not lists.**

```
import numpy as np
import numdifftools as nd

# Define your function 
# Can be R^n -> R^n as long as you use numpy arrays as output
def f(x):
    return np.array([x[0],x[1]])

# Define your Jacobian function
f_jacob = nd.Jacobian(f)

# Use your Jacobian function at any point you want.
# In our case, for a R² -> R² function, it returns a 2x2 matrix with all partial derivatives of all outputs wrt all inputs
print(f_jacob([1,2]))
```

Execution returns

```
[[1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]]
```

Comment: [Link to the doc updated](https://numdifftools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/numdifftools.core.Jacobian.html)